# Creating bitmap from jpeg data

Tags: c++, image, directx, jpeg, direct2d

I have a program that is constantly receiving about 60 `jpeg` files in **memory**, per second, and as bytes, and I'm looking to use `d2d` to simply create a bitmap from that in memory `jpeg` data, and then render it onto the screen.

What is the most efficient way to do this? I tested `CreateDecoderFromStream`, along with creating a convertor to convert it into a `d2d` compatible bitmap, and all of that combined seems to be the main bottleneck in my application. This simple code in `c#` using `winforms` somehow beats `d2d` at converting `jpegs`:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, len))
{
    // stream is created for every single stream, and it just wraps bytes, which is an array of bytes.

    // Literally just calls gdiploadimagefromstream found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-bitmap-flat
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
}
```

It seems I could use `IWICImagingFactory::CreateBitmapFromMemory` like @Simon Mourier suggested, but that seems to take in raw bytes. **My data is in `jpeg` format.**

**Edit:
I did some more specific benchmarking, and I'm 100% sure that  `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget::CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap` is the cause of 99% of my performance issues. Is there any way around this?**

Is there a more efficient way? Or should I use something like `libjpeg-turbo` instead and just create a raw bitmap from that?

Comment: Unless the jpeg decompression is going to the gpu, I'm not certain that decoding at 60fps is achievable on a single core with conventional RAM.  Assuming a 400x300 image at 60fps. Decodinng at that rate is 172 mbit/sec of RGB data across the bus.  Even if you have the right APIs, are you sure this is going to work?

Comment: @selbie Wait, but 172mb/s is only about 21.5MB/s. I think JPEG decoding is faster than that?

Comment: I could be mistaken.  I just know from past experience that using jpeg as a streaming video codec has shown to be impractical.  But I've been thinking of this from the encoding side. Consider benchmarking. Perhaps the technology has gotten better.

Comment: You need to use WIC first to load the JPEG from memory IWICImagingFactory::CreateBitmapFromMemory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicimagingfactory-createbitmapfrommemory and then ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-createbitmapfromwicbitmap(iwicbitmapsource_constd2d1_bitmap_properties__id2d1bitmap)

Comment: @SimonMourier But `CreateBitmapFromMemory` takes in raw bytes? It has to take in values such as the stride, and format even though the data is jpeg.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you had raw data in memory. If you have raw jpeg in memory, then yes, you will have to decode them first using any of the CreateDecoderXXX methods. D2D bitmaps are usually (A)RGB buffers (in GPU).